# How to stop trigger('click')?

Tags: jquery

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  jQuery('#imgZoomin').trigger('click');
}, 52000);
```

Actually the above code i given here. It correctly trigger on the time. but not stopped, the same action doing continuously again and again.So how to stopped the trigger.? I required the trigger is one time is Enough. How to stop the continuous trigger?

Comment: `setTimeout´ fires only once. Either `setTimeout` is being called more than once, or `jQuery('#imgZoomin').trigger('click')` doesn't do what you expect it to.

Comment: i would like to click the button automatically. I given that code only, but its coming again and again. #David Hedlund

Comment: i think your setTimeout is in the click event handler itself which causing it to trigger it again!

Comment: show us your complete code

Comment: May be, How to avoid this Problem? # ScanQR

Comment: #ScanQR : that only i given here. I cannot add anything on that code.

Comment: @EdwinBenjamin It seems that you are calling this settimeout function in your function which you are calling on trigger click, Please show the function you are calling on click of #imgZoomin. Thanks

Comment: @ManojLodhi:  Right Manoj. I given that setTimeout in inside of one Function Only.

Comment: And when are you calling that function ?

Comment: that function is used to create a graph. End of the Function i given the setTimeout.

Comment: Please just make sure this function is calling only once. Because setTimeout function fires only once, untill you are calling it more than once, So please check if the function where you called setTimeout is calling only once.

Comment: SetTimeout is only set to call once. I am sure your code is getting called more than once.

Comment: @Gogol: Right Gogol, Actually I given Inside of a One Function, That One is Like a loop. So it's Comes again. Thanx Gogol,Manoj,ScanQR and David and Raju

Answer (score 1):

try to use below code

```html
var flag=false;
setTimeout(function() {
  if(flag==false)
  {
  jQuery('#imgZoomin').trigger('click');
    flag=true;
  }
}, 52000
```

Answer (score 1):

The setTimeout works just one time. If the function is excecuted again it means that it is inside a loop or another function called more than 1 times. Add a variable and a statement for avoid that your function is called more than 1 time

```
var count = 0;
setTimeout(function() {
  if (count == 0) {
    jQuery('#imgZoomin').trigger('click');
    count++;
  }
}, 52000);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add disabled attribute to your button after first click, or use clearTimeout before a new timeout.